# CSS Code styling - background color is missing on empty lines

Tags: css, wordpress, code-formatting

I'm hoping this is simple.  I'm not a CSS guy.

I'm trying to make some code look a little better on a blog and I have the following `<code>` CSS style.

```
code {
        display: block;
        white-space:normal;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        font: 1em, 'Courier New', Courier, Fixed;
        padding: 7px;
        margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    }
```

This is working fine for me, except where there are line breaks in the code contained in my `<code>` tag, the background color is white not light gray.

Is there a CSS tweak I can make to force my entire `<code>` block have a background color of gray?

Thanks.

Comment:  If I put a space on the empty line, I get what I want - a gray background on that line.

Comment2: I have only plain text inside of my `<code>` `</code>` tags.  Ideally I don't want to mark up my code w/ tags.  Just cut and paste inside of the `<code>` tags and have it look decent.

Final Comment: After reading [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing%5FCode%5Fin%5FYour%5FPosts) as suggested by mercator below, I finally went with this.  I subclassed the `<pre>` tag and got want I needed.  A nicely shaded boxes to offset my example code blocks.

```
 pre.code {
    color: black;
    border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
font-size: 1.1 em; 
margin: 7px; 
padding: 7px; 
background: #eeeeee
 }
```

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: @SLaks, the question was clearer before your edit. I would consider putting the `<code>` text back. I could do it, but didn't want to get into a edit war :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to work fine for me, but then I don't know what the contents of your `<code>` tags are.

There's a few oddities in your CSS in any case:

- I probably wouldn't use `display: block`, but wrap the tags in a `<p>` or `<pre>` instead. Changing it to a block like that still won't allow you to nest block-level tags inside it, and it would still need to be inside a block-level tag itself. CSS doesn't change the HTML syntax and semantics. Do you have any block-level tags within your code tags?
- Why did you set `white-space: normal`? That's a little unusual for a code block. How exactly are you formatting your code? Are you adding `<p>` or `<br>` tags in there? Why don't you use `white-space: pre`, or perhaps `white-space: pre-wrap`?
- Your `font` declaration is broken. There shouldn't be a comma between the `1em` and the font names. Browsers would now simply parse that as if `1em` is the name of a font family, I think, and then fall back on `Courier New`, since `1em` doesn't exist.
- I think you meant to say `monospace` instead of `Fixed`. Or is `Fixed` the actual name of a font face? You'd better add the generic `monospace` anyway.
- More of a nitpick: you can collapse those 4 margins down to one value too.

I'm not sure if any of these are really the cause of your problems. The first two are the most likely candidates. Nothing strange happened on the quick tests I did, but some of your *other* CSS might be creating the problems in combination with some of these points.

**Ah, wait a minute...** I see now that you're talking about making *"some code look a little better on a blog"*. The blog software is automatically adding paragraph tags around blocks of text separated by blank lines. Those are responsible for the white.

I suppose that's also why you added `white-space: normal`. The blog software is already adding line breaks and everything automatically (with `<p>` and `<br>` tags), so using `pre` added a whole bunch of extra space.

Try using the `<pre><code>` tags combination like StackOverflow does. Using the `<pre>` tag will probably (hopefully) prevent the blog software from messing with your code.

For WordPress, have a look at their article "[Writing Code in Your Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts)."

Comment: The `1em` is not pointless, you may need to override either a browser setting, or another style in the CSS somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, yes, true. I removed that.

Comment: Thanks mercator for the help mercator.  It's a WP blog.  Let me try out some of your ideas and fixes....

Comment: You're welcome. I was just editing in a link to a WordPress article about this while you added your comment...

Comment: What an answer, covering all the bases :) @Paul, a live, online example would be really, really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting an explicit width. Not sure why that would work. I sometimes add a border while testing to see where my box is and what it looks like. I know you can do that with web debuggers like firebug, sometimes it's simpler and might even have side effects.

add:

```
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #eee;
```

See if that helps, maybe change the border color to #000 to see where the boundaries are.

Answer (score 1):

Without some HTML and/or a test page, it's quite difficult to know what could be causing the problem. I would look at the `line-height` property though - it often causes these kind of problems.

Comment: The HTML is just <code> lines of code here w/ no other tags </code>.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a sample page where the problem occurs?